# Pointing .co.uk, .org & .info to main .com domain

Tags: domains, redirects, top-level-domains

I have a client who has multiple domains .co.uk, .org and .info and would like to point them to the main .com domain name.

They have changed the nameservers of the .co.uk, .org and .info domains.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It's unclear what's the problem

Comment: I would like to add the .co.uk .org and .info to the .com record if possible.

Comment: This is clear but what's unclear is what's your problem. It's possible to let the other domains point to the .com but what's your problem? Have you set the parameter and they don't point to the .com? Do you see any error?

Comment: Sorry, my issue is do I need to create a different record for each of the TLDs or can I incorporate it into the main .com record?

Comment: Sorry, always unclear. Do you want redirect .co.uk, .org and .info to .com? Do you want to know how doing these redirects?

Comment: Zistoloen that is right

Answer (score 1):

In order to redirect .co.uk, .org and .info to .com, good practices refer to use 301 redirections. There are various method to apply these redirections. My favourite are:

- Doing it with [.htaccess file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/howto/htaccess.html) if you use Apache web server (or specific file for another web server)

  You can follow [this](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93633) for more information.
- Doing it with index.php file on other TLDs root. Here's an example:

  ```
  header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently", false, 301);  
  header("Location:http://www.example.com");  
  exit();
  ```

Comment: If the NAMESERVERs for these other domains have been changed to point to the hosting account, then these domains will first need to be setup as parked (or addon) domains on the hosting account for the site to accept requests to these domains. You can then setup 301 redirects, checking the HTTP_HOST through which the site has been accessed...